# how to add ainmation in GoRouter flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, frontend

**how to add ainmation in GoRouter flutter**
and also if the animation class can sit in a stand alone file so that i can have so many animation classes to call on different pages.
[code source](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router/example)

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String title = 'GoRouter Example: Declarative Routes';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp.router(
        routerConfig: _router,
        title: title,
      );

  final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
            const Page1Screen(),
        routes: <GoRoute>[
          GoRoute(
            path: 'page2',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                const Page2Screen(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the **CustomTranstionPage** to create a custom transition animation.

***An example:***

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
    
class CustomSlideTransition extends CustomTransitionPage<void> {
      CustomSlideTransition({super.key, required super.child})
          : super(
              transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
              transitionsBuilder: (_, animation, __, child) {
                return SlideTransition(
                  position: animation.drive(
                    Tween(
                      begin: const Offset(1.5, 0),
                      end: Offset.zero,
                    ).chain(
                      CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
    }


// In your router:

GoRoute(
    name: 'my_page',
    path: '/my_page',
    pageBuilder: (_, state) {
      return CustomSlideTransition(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: MyPage(),
      );
   },
),
```

Comment: can i separate the class from the GoRoute instance?

Comment: @Georgegoldman sure it's just a CustomTransitionPage

Answer (score -1):

*"The **builder** is responsible for building the Widget to display on screen. Alternatively, you can use **pageBuilder** to customize the transition animation when that route becomes active."*